# Is it correct to add LDAP users to LDAP group using RDN only?

Tags: ldap

I have created the framework that assumes that LDAP users are added to LDAP groups using DN only.

E.g. Group DN `cn=users,cn=groups,dc=example,dc=com`

User DN `cn=admin,dc=example,dc=com`

I expect the following value in the `uniqueMember` attribute of the group:
`uniqueMember=“cn=admin,dc=example,dc=com”`

Unfortunately, a customer add a user using its RDN only:
`uniqueMember=“cn=admin”`

Is it correct to add LDAP users to LDAP group using RDN only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. `uniqueMember` is defined as a complete DN.